# Why cant i find the node command configuration in Elastic Beanstalk in AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy my back-end with elastic beanstalk and i need to configure the node command, yet in all the videos i have seen it should be in configuration => Software Configuration => container options.
[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mdjN.png)

[Software Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UDSx.png)

Comment: I am having this same problem! Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am facing the same problem